# Recursive Make passes incorrect -j argument

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, devtoolset

I'm running make (GNU Make 3.82) with a recursive Makefile.
I'm running `make -j2` in order to spawn only 2 processes in parallel.
The internal Makefile is called with $(MAKE).

However, it looks like the internal Makefile (which was started by the main Makefile) spawns processes infinitely as if it was given `-j` and not `-j2`.

Trying to verify this, I dumped the environment variables of the child "make":

```
# pgrep -a make
17218 make -j2
17227 make -C obj_dir/ -f Vf1_package.mk ...

# strings /proc/17227/environ
...
MAKEFLAGS= --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j
...
```

`MAKEFLAGS` is not set explicitly anywhere, and `-j` is only provided in the command line and doesn't appear anywhere in the makefiles. So it seems like "make" itself decided to strip the "2" from the `-j` argument when composing the `MAKEFLAGS` for the child "make".

Any idea what could cause "make" to set `MAKEFLAGS` to `-j` instead of `-j2`?

---

#### Update 1

I've identified the problem, but I still don't understand why it happens and how to fix that.

The problem is that the job server doesn't work well when the sub-make is running under [SCL](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-8/) context.
This is required because I need the sub-make to use specific gcc toolchain.

```
SCL      = scl enable devtoolset-8
...
sub_make:
    $(SCL) "$(MAKE) -C $(SUB_MAKE_DIR) ... "
```

When running like this, the sub-make spawns infinite number of jobs. When SCL is removed, it works as expected.

- Why does SCL interfere with make's job server?
- How can I solve this? I know I can enable SCL before running the external Makefile, but I would like to control the toolset from within the Makefile.

---

#### Update 2

It seems to be related to the fact that SCL changes `PATH` environment variable. On the new `PATH`, "make" is newer ("GNU Make 4.2.1").

So it seems that make job server fails if the top level make is running old GNU Make 3.82 and the sub make is running newer 4.2.1 make, maybe something changed between these versions in the way make communicates with the sub-make.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that the version of `ls` has anything to do with the version of `make`; they are completely different tools.  You should run `make --version` if you want to know the version of make.  But, yes, GNU make 3.82 is very old (released over a decade ago) and there was a change to the jobserver made in GNU make 4.2 (released 5 years ago).  So you'll need to use the same version of make if you want this to work.

Comment: @MadScientist Sorry for the typo, that's "GNU Make 4.2.1", not ls, after `PATH` changed by SCL. I've fixed the question. The change to the jobserver is the source of the problem. It means that SCL cannot be used inside make in order to run sub-make with newer toolchain. Do you have more information regarding the nature of the change to the jobserver?

Comment: It's in the NEWS file for GNU make.  You can see the latest copy in Git: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS  There's a mention about it in the 4.2 release info.  Basically the jobserver interface was published as an externally visible facility that other tools could use (other multithreaded GNU build tools like the GNU linker etc. can take jobserver tokens as well so that they don't overwhelm the system).  As part of moving from an internal only to externally visible facility some naming had to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong here.  The top-level make knows how many total jobs there are and it arranges for all the sub-makes to share those jobs through the jobserver (that's what the `--jobserver-fds` entry in `MAKEFLAGS` is for).  The sub-makes don't need to know how many total jobs there are, they just need to know how to ask if they can start a new job.

In the very old version of GNU make you are using there is *no way*, from a sub-make, to know what the specific `-j` number for this build.

Starting with GNU make 4.2, make will add the specific `-j` value to `MAKEFLAGS` for informational purposes even though it's still not used.

**EDIT**

I don't know anything about `scl` or how it works.  But, the GNU make jobserver works by sharing file descriptors across all the sub-makes.  If this `scl` tool is interfering with that, say by forcing all file descriptors to be closed, or running the sub-make inside a docker image where obviously it can't access these shared file descriptors, or some similar thing, then it clearly cannot work with the jobserver feature and you'll have to run the entire make inside the scl.

An option is to not put the `-j` on the outer make but instead run a single inner make using `-j`, inside `scl`.

Comment: So why would the sub-make spawn infinite number of jobs, and not only 2 in parallel? Something is still wrong here. When I start the sub-make directly it only spawns 2 jobs (with make -j2), this only happens when the sub-make is run from within the main make.

Comment: There is no way that should happen.  The fact that it happens has nothing do to with the unadorned `-j` showing up in your `MAKEFLAGS` so we need to look elsewhere.  Maybe your version of GNU make has a bug; what operating system are you using?  Is your version the official GNU make version or a patched version?  Can you reproduce this "infinite number of jobs" with a smaller example you could post here?  We'll need to see the rules that invoke the sub-make, and the rules that appear to build more than two targets at the same time.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the root cause but not a solution. See the update on the question.

Comment: SCL changes `PATH` such that the sub-make is a newer version of "make". Make jobserver seems to fail across make versions. See "Update 2".

Answer (score 0):

Can you run `make --print-data-base`  and check if you get proper value of `-j`.

May be execute a simple test example as shown below where you can test to check if gnu make is able to compile multiple files in parallel to generate object files and is giving correct values of -j:

```
# .SILENT:
.PHONY:compile objs
TARGET = program.exe
CC=gcc

SOURCES = file_1.c file_2.c file_3.c
OBJ_FILES:= $(SOURCES:.c=.o)


objs: $(OBJ_FILES)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

all: test 

# Enable parallel compilation
compile:
    make -j ${NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS} objs

link : compile $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(OBJ_FILES) -o $@

test: link 
    # Execute test script
    echo "Executing test script"
```

Command to execute : **make test**
This will help you debug and also check if there is issue of gnu-make or some internal bug or make is unable to run in parallel as it did not find anything. I have use `${NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS}` to use all the available processors, you can change it's value and test different runs as per your need.

***EDIT***
Unfortunately I am not aware about sc1.If scl is the root cause identified, then option would be run the entire make inside sc1. or maye be would be good to test once by explicitly passing -j2 inside the sc1 as maybe global flags are not getting passed to SC1.

Comment: See update on the question related to SCL